# Managing Json Response with Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

Here is the backstory:

I am trying to pull data via an api:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(r.json()), orient='list') // preferably i would use pd.io.json.json_normalize but it throws an error
```

Sample Json response(slightly simplified):

```
{'childCollectors': [12345678,],
  'Param1': False,
  'creationTime': '2017-01-19T18:53:28Z',
  'physicalSerialNumber': ‘someserialnumberhere’,
  'accountName': ‘account name’,
  'Param2’: False,
  'Param3’: None,
  ‘Param4’: None,
  'type': ‘somesupersecrettype :)’,
  'timeout': 5,
  'points': [],
  'archived': False,
  ‘Class’: ‘name’,
  'firstReportedTime': '2017-10-26T00:24:12Z',
  'deviceIdentifier': '255CD895348K',
  'usenetmetering': False,
  'vendor': ‘vendor name’,
  'reportingIntervalLengthInMillis': 300000,
  'id': 12145278,
  'manualReadings': [],
  'readingsMultiplier': 1,
  'outageTimeInMillis': 43200000,
  'multiplier': 1,
  'parentPoint': None,
  'buildingName': ‘buildingname',
  'queryable': True,
  'replications': [],
  'downwardCommunications': [‘something here’],
  'buildings': [associatedbuildingid],
  'collectorClassDetails': {'identifierName': 'SERIAL_NUMBER',
   'multiplierLabel': ‘supersecretlabel’,
   'displayName': ‘fancyversionofClass’,
   'downwardCommunications': [’something here’],
   'vendor': ‘vendor’,
   'isPhysicalMeter': False,
   'name': 'fancyversionofClass',
   'upwardCommunications': [‘somesuacyformat’],
   'gateway': True},
  'name': 'Gateway 1',
  'primaryBuilding': associatedbuildingid,
  'parentCollector': None,
  'metrics': [‘well duh metrics’],
  'upwardCommunications': [‘internet’]}
```

My Question is:

1) When I get a weird json format response like the above, what is the best practice of converting it to something more standard so that the data can be extracted and utilized. IE I personally want to create a source that contains all of the childCollector ID's to use to query data.

Sorry if this question is too specific but I am still learning python and would love to learn more about parsing data :)

Comment: What exactly do you consider weird about the JSON response and what should the output look like?

Comment: @roganjosh i just realized I was going around in a circle(need more java). For me the response was weird because I could not use pd.io.json.json_normalize and when I ran the json response through a json validator it said it was an invalid format.

Comment: Well it is an invalid format now because what you posted is a python dictionary, with custom quotation marks thrown in too (`‘` is not valid in JSON or Python). `json.dumps(r.json())` would fail if the initial response from the server isn't valid, though.

Comment: @roganjosh thats the thing, this is their typical nested json response.  If   'collectorClassDetails': {'identifierName': None, then I run into this: KeyError: 'identifierName'. I was hoping to get some guidance(docs that I haven't looked at yet?) with how to deal with this type of response and how to parse it out into a dataframe.